# Nested regular expressions

Tags: regex

I was trying to write a regular expression that matches and captures both the full date, as well as the year of the date.

Example

```
TEXT: JAN 2013
CAPTURE: JAN 2013, 2013
```

I tried to use:

```
[a-z]{3}\s(\d{4},*){2}
```

But this one doesn't work. If anyone could help.

Comment: Why the trailing {2} ?

Comment: `(\d{4},*){2}` is capturing the year twice. Try `(\d{4})` instead.

Comment: Why not just ([a-z]{3})\s(\d{4}) ?

Comment: Why would you even match for `,`? It isn't in your text... Also - can you please add some details? What does "doesn't work" mean? Why can't you `.split(' ')`? What language are you using?

Comment: I tried that earlier that did not work. I thought since they need to capture the year twice i added {2} but that does not work too.

Comment: What library for regexp or at least language you use?

Comment: I am just learning regular expressions. I thought this one needed some kind of back referencing. I am trying to run these expressions against regex tool.

Comment: There are few styles of giving regular expressions. For example, I used a lot of regexps, but haven't seen things like {3}, {2}.

Comment: i can't find any good examples for back referencing either. I am unable to capture (, 2013). May be i did not make my question clear. The given string that we have is JAN 2013 but I want to capture JAN 2013, 2013

Comment: And you can't find in what programming language you are writing, either? Never mind, I found this.

Comment: You can't capture "JAN 2013" as "JAN 2013, 2013". You can at most capture it into two separate strings "JAN 2013", "2013". Capturing do not perform any text formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The following regexp gives you two capture groups:

```
([A-Z]{3}\s(\d{4}))
```

where the first will contain "JAN 2013" and the second "2013".

Example in Perl:

```
$text = "JAN 2013";
@m = $text =~ /([A-Z]{3}\s(\d{4}))/;
print "First capture: $m[0]\n";
print "Second capture: $m[1]\n";
```

Output:

```
First capture: JAN 2013
Second capture: 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Code in C# for what you wanted (according to comments).

For references you may look *MSDN - Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference*, here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\A([a-z]{3}\s+(\d{4}))\Z",
                    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

MatchCollection match = r.Matches(text);
if (match.Count == 1)
{
     GroupCollection captures = match[0].Groups;
     String theCaptureYouWanted = captures[1] + ", " + captures[2];
     ...
```